# Replace character in array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I am trying to replace the 8th character in each element of an array.  I know JavaScript does not have a built-in function to replace string characters.  I was able to find to potentially helpful code on this site.  They accept strings as parameters, but when I pass in a array such as cookies[0], it does not change anything in the string.  Why is that?  Is there a way I can get this to work?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var cookies = ["cartItem1", "cartItem2", "cartItem3", "cartItem4"];

function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}

function delCookie(){
    cookies.splice(0,1);
    setCharAt(cookies[0], 8, "Z");

}

delCookie();
```

I also tried it this way:

```
var cookies = ["cartItem1", "cartItem2", "cartItem3", "cartItem4"];


String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
};

function delCookie2(){
    cookies.splice(0,1);
    cookies[0].replaceAt(8, "Z");
}

delCookie2();
```

Comment: Additional information about the answers given:  In JavaScript, strings are `immutable`, which means that they cannot be changed -- ever.  They can only be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your methods (`setCharAt` and `replaceAt`) are returning the result, which means you have to set it:

```
function delCookie() {
   cookies.splice(0,1);
   cookies[0] = cookies[0].replaceAt(8, "Z"); 
   //or
   // cookies[0] = setCharAt(cookies[0], 8, "Z");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "setCharAt" function doesn't actually alter the string passed in - it returns a new string with the appropriate character changed. In order to get the behavior you want, you'll have to replace the old string in your array with the new one.